# class com.android.volley.ClientError in specific phones in 5 and 6 version of android

Tags: android

class com.android.volley.ClientError in specific phones in android version 5.1 - 6 but running well in android 8.0 and 9.0

```
   public void parseHomeCategorydata(Context context){
        RequestQueue requestQ = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, Const.Base_Url+"manage/api/p_category/all/?X-Api-Key="+Const.API_KEY+"&start=0&limit=100&field=shop_id&filter="+Const.Shop_id+"&parent=0" , null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = response.getJSONObject("data");
                    JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("p_category");
                    homeCategoryRecModelArrayList = Parser.parseHomeCategoryList(jsonArray);
                    homeCategoryRecAdapter = new HomeCategoryRecAdapter(context , homeCategoryRecModelArrayList);
                    recyclerViewCategory.setAdapter(homeCategoryRecAdapter);
                    parseSliderData(context);

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        error.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
        );
        requestQ.add(jsonObjectRequest);
    }
```

Comment: Can you post the error you are getting?

Comment: class com.android.volley.ClientError

Comment: Give error stack trace in logcat. Not class.